# Vagrant provision script: echo "source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh" >> ~/.profile fails

Tags: linux, shell, vagrant

I'm running my vagrant provisioning with a *bootstrap.sh* script. The script runs fine except for one line:

```
echo "source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh" >> ~/.profile
```

This line fails. I don't get any output about it, but when I do `vagrant ssh` and check the `~/.profile` file I can see that `source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh` is not appended to the file.

How can I append `source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh` to the file so that command is sourced every time I do `vagrant ssh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell (and most other) provisioners are run as the root user using `sudo`. But for the shell provisioner you can set `privileged` attribute to `false` to run as the SSH user.

Example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh", privileged: false
end
```

See [the documentations](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) for more details.

Comment: This does not work for me. Even when running as the SSH user, I cannot append to files using `echo`. The version of `echo` used by SSH differs from the version available on the guest OS (where it is possible to execute the command if I copy and paste it there).

Answer (score 1):

Running a script with `vagrant provision`:

```
#whoami
root
#echo $HOME
/root
```

compared to running `vagrant ssh`:

```
#whoami
vagrant
#echo $HOME
/home/vagrant
```

In other words, when I use `~/.profile`, the `~` expands to `/root` in a provision script compared to when I use it after I sssh into the virtual box where it expands to `/home/vagrant`.

So in order to append the line to the `~/.profile` file that you can access with ssh, you'd need the following line in your provision script:

```
echo "source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh" >> /home/vagrant/.profile
```

If you use `printenv` you can see all the env variables set. That reveals that you could also use:

```
echo "source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh" >> $PWD/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing. Then I realized after reading @tmatilai's comment that it has actually set it for the root user!

You can do

```
sudo su -
```

to get to root. and there you will see your line appended to the file (in /root/.profile)

Also, instead of setting privileges as he suggested, you can use a fully qualified name instead:

```
echo "source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh" >> /home/vagrant/.profile
```